# Automatic mapping of OleDbType to Sql server data Type and .Net Type

Tags: sql-server, mapping, type-conversion, foxpro

I open a Foxpro file using OleDb

```
Dim connection As New OleDbConnection(String.Format("Provider=VFPOLEDB.1;Data Source={0};", dbfPath))
connection.Open()
Dim tables As DataTable = connection.GetSchema(System.Data.OleDb.OleDbMetaDataCollectionNames.Tables)
```

Then I analyze the structure of the FoxPro data

```
For Each rowTables As System.Data.DataRow In tables.Rows
   Dim columns As DataTable = connection.GetSchema(System.Data.OleDb.OleDbMetaDataCollectionNames.Columns, New [String]() {Nothing, Nothing, rowTables("table_name").ToString(), Nothing})
    For Each rowColumns As System.Data.DataRow In columns.Rows
        Console.Out.WriteLine(String.Format("{0};{1};{2};{3};{4};{5}", rowTables("table_name").ToString(), rowColumns("column_name").ToString(), rowColumns("data_type").ToString(), rowColumns("CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH").ToString(), rowColumns("NUMERIC_PRECISION").ToString(), rowColumns("NUMERIC_SCALE").ToString()))
    Next
Next
```

Now I must create a Sql server table with a compatible structure in order to load the FoxPro data (I'll use a DataReader and SqlBulkCopy).

I could use the information collected inside the For Each to build an SQL script to create the table but I would like to know if there is a **smarter way** to automatically map data types of FoxPro on Sql server, avoiding a Select Case that implements this table https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130984.aspx 
By project requirement I cannot use Entity framework (and i think it is not the right tool to load millions of records).

Comment: Is this a one-off data take-on from DBF into SQL Server?

Comment: No,  it will run several times on about 30 different tables

Answer (score 2):

If you have VFP, and this will be a one time upgrade process, have you looked into VFP from the menu  Tools -> Wizards -> Upsizing?

This will allow you to define a connection to SQL Server, then pick your database you want to upsize to.  Pick the tables and go.

If your tables are "free" tables (not associated with an actual database container), I think you can still upsize them, but it has been a while since I dug into that process, but can offer additional direction if this is an avenue you have available to run with.

Comment: Hi, unlucky they come from old Fox pro,  not the visual version, so there is not upsizing feature.

Comment: @Luca,  If they came from the Old, you could still do... Do you HAVE Visual Foxpro AVAILABLE?

Comment: I'll ask to someone if we can find and install it. Do you know if it runs on 64 bit os? Old FP cannot.

Comment: @Luca, VFP will run on a 64-bit machine, but only under the 32-bit environment (thus in C:\Program Files (x86) folder).  I still use VFP 9 on a regular basis on my 64-bit machines.

Comment: The old FoxPro for DOS will run happily on 64-bit Windows under DosBOX, and if you install Windows 3.11 under DosBOX, you can run Foxpro For Windows also.